# syntax error while specifying DOCTYPE

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

I am getting a syntax error while using the DOCTYPE  ...
actually  i have a base page and loading two iframes in it , and the doctype is specifyed in one of these iframes ..
I have some php codes before starting the html code ...

The firebug error is shown below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you paste the code where this doctype declaration occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I saw this, it was caused by an attempt to load a JavaScript but the URL was pointing to an HTML document.

Check your script srcs.

Comment: Thank you David , its somewhat similar the case with me :) . your hint helped to make it done

Comment: Similiar problem, I was trying to load a JavaScript file, but had the wrong path.

Answer (score 2):

Delete this `\n` and should be OK.

You can also insert `?>` before DOCTYPE.

Are you have e.g. `\\n` instead of `\n` in php code?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be outputting a raw `\n` after the doctype, probably caused by a PHP echo statement.

Comment: thanks pekka, but you mean after the doctype or before it? actualyy its showing in line 3 while taking the page source

Comment: @raki can you show the full source code of the first 5 lines?